# Java Random Fraction within Range

Tags: java, random

How can i Generate an array with 10 random fractions between 10/1 and 1/10 . i  have coded java class Rational to do this work .

inside Rational Class , there are some basic methods are defined . please have a look on the class .

```
public class Rational {    

    // Private instance variables
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    // Constructor
    public Rational(){

        this.numerator = 0;
        this.denominator = 1;       

    }

    // Overloaded constructor
    public Rational(int num, int den){

        this.numerator = num;
        this.denominator = den;

        reduce();

    }

    // Getter method for numerator
    public int getNumerator(){

        return this.numerator;

    }

    // Getter method for denominator
    public int getDenominator(){

        return this.denominator;

    }

    // Getter method for double
    public double toDouble(){

        return(double)this.numerator/this.denominator;

    }

    // Getter method for string
    public String toString(){       
        if(denominator == 0){

            return "ERROR";

        }            
        if(denominator == 1){

            return this.numerator + "";

        }
        else {

            return this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator;

        }
    }

    // Void method for negate
    public void negate(){

        this.numerator = -1 * numerator;

    }

    //  Void method for invert
    public void invert(){

        int flip = this.numerator;

        this.numerator = this.denominator;
        this.denominator = flip;

    }

    // Value method for addition 
    public Rational add(Rational test){

        this.numerator = (numerator * denominator) + (test.getDenominator() * test.getNumerator());
        this.denominator = test.getDenominator() * denominator;

        return new Rational(numerator,denominator);

    }

    // Euclid's GCD
    private static int gcd(int x, int y){
        if (0 == y){

            return x;

        }
        else {

            return gcd(y,x%y);

        }
    }

    // Void method for reduce, using GCD 
    public void reduce(){

        int div;        
        div = Rational.gcd(numerator, denominator);

        this.numerator = numerator/div;
        this.denominator = denominator/div;

    }

    // *Bonus* value method for multiplication 
    public Rational multiply(Rational test){

        int numx = this.numerator * test.getNumerator();
        int denx = this.denominator * test.getDenominator();

        return new Rational(numx, denx);

    }   
}
```

But i am having problem in creating that logic to generate random fraction with that specific range ...

Comment: It is not straight forward to guess a distribution for these numbers. So which distribution do you want your random numbers to have.

Comment: i am not sure with any specific distribution , can you please try with any distribution

Comment: A very simple distribution could for example pick out the numbers 1 and 2 (both are fractions in the range) with probability 1/2 each. You see, the question does not make sense without specifying a distribution.

Comment: hy thanks ... i read some posts but what i am about to assigned is that " create n random fractions between 10/1 and 1/10 and then search for the fraction 1/1. "

Comment: This still leaves room for interpretation but it seems an acceptable approach is that both, numerator and denominator in your fractions are integers in the range [1..10].

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this simple strategy. You know that your fraction is between 1/10 and 10, which means,

1/10 < num/den < 10 ...(1)

Which implies that,

den/10 < num < 10*den ...(2)

So, first randomly fix the den (choose randomly from 0 to 9). Once you have fixed this, randomly choose a number from the range den/10 to 10*den

Comment: A den of 0 does not make much sense, but otherwise it is just as arbitrary as my simple example given in the comments above.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Without a distribution that is the same as this approach :)